# Why django-background-tasks doesn't create table background_task_completedtask

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-migrations, background-task

I run package background_task_completedtask on Django 1.11 and python 3.5.2
from http://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/:

> Python: 2 & 3
>   Django: 1.8–1.11

When I run migrations I got the output:

```
- Remove field creator_content_type from completedtask
- Delete model CompletedTask
```

and migration:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('background_task', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='completedtask',
            name='creator_content_type',
        ),
        migrations.DeleteModel(
            name='CompletedTask',
        ),
    ]
```

and all gone good but when I run tasks django raise an error 
`django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: background_task_completedtask`

Why django remove this table and how can I avoid it? Should I just ignore this migration or there is some more clever way?

P.S. I already check simial questions but I didn't find the solution.

**UDP**
I can fake this migration but got another problem. django-background-tasks register each task two times (I call only one). Could you suggest how to cook it? Or some else **light weight** background queue for Django? I found a lot of them but all the projects without changes a few years.